# GPU Fan is not spinning continuously

Tags: hardware-failure, gpu, fan

I have NVidia GTX 550 Ti in my desktop computer.

Today, while I was working on the computer, my monitors went off (I work with dual monitors). After a while, I have recognized that my GPU fan does not spin continuously.

I have verified that my GPU is overheating by downloading MSI Afterburner.

Even though I set the fan speed to 100%, the fan spins a bit with huge intervals.

I have also reset the BIOS by taking of its battery and plugging back in. GPU is heating up to 90C degrees in 5-6 minutes, maybe less.

Is my GPU fan broken? What should I do to fix it?

I also think that power supply might be the issue since the fan spins. It seems the "spin" command is not given continuously.

Comment: This does indeed sound like a hardware failure associated with the GPU heatsink + fan, replace the fan+heatsink,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on Hardorman's answer. Even if the fan is 3-pin it may still be controlled by the GPU.
The common pinouts are:

```
Power [red] (Always)
RPM control [usually blue] (sometimes)
RPM feedback [usually white] (also sometimes - more likely if there's RPM control)
Ground [black] (Always)
```

If you have the tools (depending on the connector), pull all of the wires except for red and black, and see what the fan does. It should immediately spin up to full speed when it gets power (the PWM control line is pulled high internally on most fans). If it still spins intermittently, then the fan likely needs replacing.

If it doesn't spin up at all, take the blue wire, and connect it to +12V (or 5V if it's a 5V fan) somewhere on your motherboard. This should force the fan to spin up to full speed. (if you have no clue why you should do this, I wouldn't recommend doing it)

Answer (score 1):

If the GPU fan has 3 pins it is no spin control and a signal should be supplied to it constantly (via red wire with +V positive voltage). Voltage is supplied from the video card. Using voltmeter you can check voltage between the red and black (its ground) wire. If it's wrong or missing when the fan stopped - you can supply +12 V from external source wire.
If it is 4 pin fan than a control signal is provided by a video card itself. In this case a control signal is provided incorrectly. Video card BIOS update may be required.

Also take a note in BIOS or monitoring software if it shows rotation speed for the fan correctly.

Please take a note that you can power on GPU fan from any power supply - from GPU board, motherboard or PSU directly. You just need to check the correct voltage on a sticker.